# Find nth root of variable without using math operators/functions

Tags: code-golf, fastest-code, restricted-source, number-theory

Write a program which, given two positive integers *n* and *x*, will display the *n*-th root of *x* (which is also x<sup>1/n</sup>) in decimal to an accuracy of 0.00001. The program must output the resulting number in decimal, and it must work for any two numbers *n* and *x*. The variables may be defined in the program, or they may be inputted by the user, but it must work for any two positive integers.

However:

- You may not use any arithmetic operators or bitwise operators (including `+`, `*`, `^`, `>>`, etc.)
- You may not use any built-in math functions (such as `pow()`, `sqr()`, or `add()`).
- No web requests; the program must be completely independent from all outside sources.

Although I tagged this [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), a program with more code that can do the job more than 1 second faster is better. A winning program will be faster than all the other programs *by more than a second*. Time differences of less than 1 second will be considered negligible. If two programs complete within a second of each other, then the one with less code wins.

Comment: This might be doable with string operations. For [tag:fastest-code], we need a way to measure the speed of the program. I would like to say, "My program is **s** times slower than a program that uses arithmetic operators." For this, it would help to have a benchmark program, in a common language like Python, that uses arithmetic operators. The program might need to loop so it is slow enough to measure.

Comment: Is _n_ always positive? If not, what should happen when the result is an imaginary number?

Comment: @Ypnypn: `x**(1/(-n)) = 1/x**(1/n)`; if `x` is negative, then we run into complex numbers.

Comment: @KyleKanos Good point; I stand corrected.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but this problem does not seem to be possible to me.

Comment: @KyleKanos I can't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I think it's possible, I'm writing a solution, but I'm not 100% sure that my logic isn't flawed and it'll actually work!

Comment: Could you please clarify how you are going to score both by code length and speed? a) as kernigh said, please state how you will be objectively comparing runtimes b) is code length just the tie breaker? Because it's virtually impossible to get a tie for fastest code, unless you score by asymptotic complexity. If it's not the tie breaker, we need a formula how length and speed factor into a single score.

Comment: @KyleKanos, it might be possible in languages which allow you to run a loop `n` times without using arithmetic, but most C-like languages are probably ruled out.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't write in C, but wouldn't appending something to a string and then checking if it's length is over a threshold (breaking if so) work?

Comment: @Ourous strings in C don't have this kind of dynamic length.

Comment: @m.buettner Oh. Well I guess I learned something new.

Comment: Can I use `if x.sign == -1` instead of `if x < 0`, or do you consider that an operator?

Comment: @Ourous that sounds like a built-in math function to me, but what's wrong with `x < 0`? `<` is neither an arithmetic nor a bitwise operator.

Comment: @m.buettner It's a huge amount faster than `x < 0`, but now that I think about it I probably won't use either.

Comment: @m.buettner: I made some edits to make the winning criterion more clear; hope that helps. The code golf is the tie-breaker, and two programs tie if they complete within a second of each other.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Yeah, I accidentally made it impossible (because complex numbers can't be represented using a single decimal number). I changed it to positive integers, which is what I should have done from the beginning.

Comment: I hope I have fixed everything.

Comment: @TimothySmith so you are aware that requires *you* to run all submissions on your own machine in order for timings to be comparable?

Comment: @m.buettner Not necessarily. We'd just need a bit of code that can assess the speed of the computer. Then we'd be able to convert the timings to the same scale.

Comment: I believe the 1 second rule is good enough. If the actual time differences are much longer or much shorter than 1 second, then the exact speed of the computer will not matter.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as unclear, as "arithmetic operators" and "builtin math functions" are unclear terms, which do not properly cover what is allowed and what isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript

This answer doesn't satisfy all the rules, but I'm happy that at least it works. It's valid only for integers greater than one and there's no further precision.

Note that the `+` and `>` operators are used for string concatenation/comparison and the maths is behind the curtain. I hope that the `!` operator doesn't count as "arithmetic" as it operates over booleans.

```javascript
function f(x,n){for(a=(c=',')+Array(x),s=r=c;a>s;r+=c)for(i='',s=r;i!=Array(n);i+=c)s=s.split(c).join(r);return r.slice(1).length}
```

And some tests:

```
> f(125,3)
5
> f(16807,5)
7
> f(4782969,7)
9
```